# Oracle.ManagedDataAccess performance in C#

Tags: c#, oracle, performance, oracle.manageddataaccess

I am using Oracle database as my backend. For my workflow, I am building a dynamic query based on what the user has selected. This dynamic query fetches from the 5 different tables. I am fetching and reading all the columns from all 5 tables so then I can use the same logic from elsewhere as well.

*Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll* is used for the database access.

**Code:**

```
    public class ClassEx
{
    public ClassA ClassA { get; set; }
    public ClassB ClassB { get; set; }
    public ClassC ClassC { get; set; }
    public ClassD ClassD { get; set; }
    public ClassE ClassE { get; set; }

    public List<ClassEx> Select()
    {
        List<ClassEx> ex = new List<ClassEx>();
        string sql = "Select "  + (new ClaasA()).GetFullString("a") + ", "
                    + (new ClaasB()).GetFullString("b") + ", "
                    + (new ClaasC()).GetFullString("c") + ", "
                    + (new ClaasD()).GetFullString("d") + ", "
                    + (new ClaasE()).GetFullString("e") +
                " From Sysadm.TableA a, Sysadm.TableB b, Sysadm.TableC c, Sysadm.TableD d, Sysadm.TableE e" +
                " Where a.Col1 = b.Col2" +
                " And a.Col5 = c.Col2" +
                " And a.Col6 = d.Col2" + 
                " And a.Col10 = e.Col2";

        GenericDataReader dr = new GenericDataReader(sql);

        while(dr.Read())
        {
            ClassEx dummy = new ClassEx();

            dummy.ClassA = new ClassA(dr);
            dummy.ClassB = new ClassB(dr);
            dummy.ClassC = new ClassC(dr);
            dummy.ClassD = new ClassD(dr);
            dummy.ClassE = new ClassE(dr);

            ex.Add(dummy);
        }

        return ex;
    }
}



public ClassA
{
    public int Col1 {get;set;}
    ...
    public DateTime? Col30 {get;set;}

    public ClassA(GenericDataReader dr)
    {
        Col1 = dr.GetInt("A_Col1")
        Col2 = dr.GetString("A_Col2")
        ....
        Col30 = dr.GetDateTime("A_Col30")
    }

    public string GetFullString(string alias)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(alias))
                    alias = alias + ".";

        return  alias + "A_Col1, " + 
            alias + "A_Col2, " +
            ...
            alias + "A_Col30"
    }
}

public ClassB
{
    public int Col1 {get;set;}
    ...
    public DateTime? Col30 {get;set;}

    public ClassB(GenericDataReader dr)
    {
        Col1 = dr.GetInt("B_Col1")
        Col2 = dr.GetString("B_Col2")
        ....
        Col30 = dr.GetDateTime("B_Col30")
    }

    public string GetFullString(string alias)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(alias))
                    alias = alias + ".";

        return  alias + "B_Col1, " + 
            alias + "B_Col2, " +
            ...
            alias + "B_Col30"
    }
}

public ClassC
{
    public int Col1 {get;set;}
    ...
    public DateTime? Col25 {get;set;}

    public ClassC(GenericDataReader dr)
    {
        Col1 = dr.GetInt("C_Col1")
        Col2 = dr.GetString("C_Col2")
        ....
        Col25 = dr.GetDateTime("C_Col25")
    }

    public string GetFullString(string alias)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(alias))
                    alias = alias + ".";

        return  alias + "C_Col1, " + 
            alias + "C_Col2, " +
            ...
            alias + "C_Col25"
    }
}

public ClassD
{
    public int Col1 {get;set;}
    ...
    public DateTime? Col10 {get;set;}

    public ClassD(GenericDataReader dr)
    {
        Col1 = dr.GetInt("D_Col1")
        Col2 = dr.GetString("D_Col2")
        ....
        Col10 = dr.GetDateTime("D_Col10")
    }

    public string GetFullString(string alias)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(alias))
                    alias = alias + ".";

        return  alias + "D_Col1, " + 
            alias + "D_Col2, " +
            ...
            alias + "D_Col10"
    }
}

public ClassE
{
    public int Col1 {get;set;}
    ...
    public DateTime? Col35 {get;set;}

    public ClassE(GenericDataReader dr)
    {
        Col1 = dr.GetInt("E_Col1")
        Col2 = dr.GetString("E_Col2")
        ....
        Col35 = dr.GetDateTime("E_Col35")
    }

    public string GetFullString(string alias)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(alias))
                    alias = alias + ".";

        return  alias + "E_Col1, " + 
            alias + "E_Col2, " +
            ...
            alias + "E_Col35"
    }
}
```

Everything work well. Query execution does not take even a second to execute. However, **while loop takes 40 seconds to read 750 records**.
Which is unacceptable. Can you please help me in improving the while loop.
I am not sure how best it can read all the record in fastest way.

Comment: First of all,  profile your code, put some log there and carefully log the times taken to do the query vs your process on each loop. Then you will have more information to know where the bottleneck is.

Comment: I did that. Query execution took less than a second. And for the reference, I just executed the logic. And here are some results:

Before execution: 22hrs 35mins 56sec
After query execution: 22:35:56
Before while loop: 22:35:56
At the end of loop: 22:36:52

Comment: @GuillermoGerard: You can clearly see the time difference between before and after the while loop.

Comment: Do you have to use a `DataReader`? Do you need to get/initialize all those objects at once?

Comment: @Jimenemex: It was a bug in my DataReader. I have resolved it and now I do receive result it in 2 seconds. Thanks.

Comment: @PrashantDesai `DataReader` is notorious for having awkward performance issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you so much friends for your response.

I have found a bug in my data reader itself when commented out one after another to see the issue. I have found that in one case, it always going in the exception and so it slows down my data reader.

After solving the exception, now I do receive my result in 2 seconds.
Solved!

Thank you once again :)